# Memory usage of rmiregistry

Tags: java, memory, rmiregistry

The other night the oom-killer was summoned on a linux machine that's been running nicely for a while now because overall RAM usage went out of control at some point. The output of that in /var/log/messages was a little surprising to me, in that it showed the rmiregistry process using almost 1G of memory. Our system is very simple and only binds only one object to the rmiregistry, which is just a collection of static methods. So that object itself uses almost no memory. On a normal system the size of that process is more like 30M, which still seems awfully high to me. Other than loading the classes serialized by the bound object, and maybe some representation of the bound object somehow, what is actually stored in the rmiregistry process? I'm using OpenJDK 1.6.0_33.

Answer (score 0):

> Other than loading the classes serialized by the bound object, and maybe some representation of the bound object somehow, what is actually stored in the rmiregistry process?

Nothing. It just contains a hash table mapping Strings to Remotes, which implies loading the class of the Remote (usually a stub) and all the classes it depends on, recursively until closure. The rest of it is all JVM overhead.